# Help with yq assignment

Tags: text-processing, yaml

I'm trying to use [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) to update the static IP on an ubuntu machine via the netcfg yaml file.

My file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 10.10.100.1/24
      gateway4: 10.10.100.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

The command I'm trying:

```
$ yq --version
yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.16.2
$ yq '(.. | select(has("addresses")).addresses) = ["10.10.200.1/24"]' 01-netcfg.yaml
Error: unknown command "(.. | select(has(\"addresses\")).addresses) = [\"10.10.200.1/24\"]" for "yq"
Run 'yq --help' for usage.
```

I adapted that command from a [guide](https://fabianlee.org/2022/12/20/yq-update-deeply-nested-elements-in-yaml/) I found which shows a similar example:

```
yq '(.. | select(has("tags")).tags) = ["coreos","arm64"]' company-servers.yaml
```

Nothing I'm trying is working though, even trying a simple example from the [author's documentation](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/assign-update) fails:

```
$ yq '.network.version = "3"' 01-netcfg.yaml
Error: unknown command ".network.version = \"3\"" for "yq"
Run 'yq --help' for usage.
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You use dash or bash?

Comment: @K-att- bash 3 more to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is caused by my inability to read documentation and the slightly outdated version of yq that is installed by the apt repository.

yq requires a command and in this case I need to use the [`eval` command](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/commands/evaluate), which is the default as of v4.18.1 but since I am using 4.16~ it needs to be explicitly specified.

Additionally I needed to add a check for the `dhcp4` key otherwise I would also overwrite the nameservers.addresses array.

```
$ yq eval '(.. | select(has("addresses") and has("dhcp4")).addresses) = ["10.10.200.1/24"]' 01-netcfg.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 10.10.200.1/24
      gateway4: 10.10.100.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```